# While I am detecting shapes from an image using open CV in python, the outer border is also recognized, what can I do to stop this?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, border, object-detection, shapes

While I am detecting shapes from an image using open CV, the outer border is also recognized. What can I do to stop this?

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\laksh\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\E-Yantra\\task_1a_explore_opencv\\task_1a_explore_opencv\\Task_1A_Part1\\Samples\\Sample1.png")
#print(img)
img2 = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\laksh\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\E-Yantra\\task_1a_explore_opencv\\task_1a_explore_opencv\\Task_1A_Part1\\Samples\\Sample1.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX 
    
imgGrey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh= cv2.threshold(imgGrey,240,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


for contour in contours:
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,0.01* cv2.arcLength(contour, True),True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx ],-1 ,(0,0,0),5)
cv2.imshow("shapes",img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.closeAllWindows()
```

This image shows that the the outer rectangle as well as the two internal shapes are recogonised:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That happens because your background is not black. OpenCV sees it as large rectangle. To avoid it, change bg color, or just remove rectangle with image size from list of detected shapes. You also can find gradients and plot fat black frame around your image, to remove edges from background.